# Statistics Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that the number of eggs laid by a certain insect has a Poisson distribution with mean λ. The probability that any one of the eggs hatches is p. Assume that the eggs hatch independently of one another. Let Y denote the number of eggs which hatch.
I am trying to find E(Y), Var(Y), and P(Y=1).

Let N denote the number of eggs, then E(Y)=EE(Y|N)=E(N)p=λp. Is this right first off?

Then for the variance, Var(Y) would equal λp also correct?

And for P(Y=1), would this just equal p?

Thanks for any help!

Where would I find the proof? I'm new to this site.

Comment: The variance turns out to be $\lambda p$. The probability that $Y=1$ turns out to be $\lambda p e^{-\lambda p}$. he random variable $Y$ has Poisson distribution parameter $\lambda p$. Proofs have been written a few times on MSE.